# LibGDX Java game: Creating a stopwatch

Tags: java, android, timer, libgdx

I am creating a game using LibGDX for android. The goal of the game is to dodge as many falling objects as you can while a timer keeps track of how long you have been playing. Once the player contacts a falling object, the game is over and the screen is set to a GameOver screen.

My problem is figuring out the best way to create a stopwatch to track the players progress. I have looked into the timer class built into Java, but I don't know if that is the best component to use. Does anyone have any insight?

Thanks much, guys!

Comment: What about take System.currentTimeMillis() at start and finish (System.currentTimeMillis() - oldcurrentTimeMillis)?

Comment: This would work great if I wanted to keep track of the time in the background, then display it when two units collide on the GameOver screen. When collision, display System.currentTimeMillis() - oldcurrentTimeMillis. If possible, I wanted to keep track of the score real-time and display a clock in the corner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store a `float playTime` which starts at `0.0f`.
Every render cycle you increase it by `float delta` or `Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()` (its the same).
The you can use a `BitMapFont`, for example, to draw it. You can also use `Stage` and use an UI-Widged, for example `Label` and set its background to a `Texture` of a stopwatch. Set the text of the `BitMapFont` to the `playTime`. A simple version of this:
Render mehtod:

```
playTime+=delta;
font.draw(Float.toString(playTime), x, y);
```

Comment: I am new to Android developement but I pretty good with Java but one thing that confuses be about a lot of the exampled I have seen is the use of "f" in variables, like your post, "0.0f". What is the f? Other than that one aspect, I like your idea a lot!

Comment: `f` is for `float`, which is the same as `double`, with half precision and therefor needs only half of the space. By writing `f` after a number you say, that it is a `float`.